# ASP.NET Core MVC and EF Core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have question in regarding how to add parameter see my codes below:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Edit(Employee emp)
    {
        try
        {

            Employee updateEmp = _Context.Employee.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Idemployee == emp.Idemployee);
            updateEmp.Address = emp.Address;
            updateEmp.Age = emp.Age;
            updateEmp.ContactNumber = emp.ContactNumber;
            updateEmp.FullName = emp.FullName;
            updateEmp.Gender = emp.Gender;
            updateEmp.IsActive = emp.IsActive;

            _Context.Employee.Update(updateEmp);
            _Context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to do here is I am trying to extract the emp.Idemployee from the querystring but it couldn't and redirect me to the error null exception.

I am using a model to extract the details form the cshtml.

```
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var editEmployee = _Context.Employee.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Idemployee == id);

        return View(editEmployee);
    }
```

I don't know whats wrong with it but all of the other information are extracted except for Idemployee.

```html
@model Demo101.DAL.Entities.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Employee";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

<form asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Edit" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

        <!--FullName-->
        <label asp-for="Idemployee" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Idemployee, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Idemployee)
        </div>

        <!--FullName-->
        <label asp-for="FullName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FullName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName)
        </div>

        <!--Age-->
        <label asp-for="Age" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>

        <!--ContactNumber-->
        <label asp-for="ContactNumber" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactNumber)
        </div>

        <!--Address-->
        <label asp-for="Address" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
        </div>

        <!--Gender-->
        <label asp-for="Gender" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Gender, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender)
        </div>

        <!--IsActive-->
        <label asp-for="IsActive" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive)
        </div>

        <!--Create Button-->
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Edit Employee" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you using the Employee Model on the CSHTML Page?  It would help if you posted the cshtml code as well.

Comment: Hi, @JasonH, yes i'm using it on my CSHTML, I'll update my post right away...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at my code below, give this a go

```
<!--IdEmployee-->
<label asp-for="Idemployee" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Idemployee, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Idemployee)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Idemployee)
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your view does not contain any field with `Employee` value. You have label, you have validation message, but not value itself. Thus, you have no value in POST to server.

Add somewhere inside form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Idemployee)
```